# DataSource in DataGridView

Tags: winforms, datagridview

I this code

```
public class Test
         {
             public string name;
             public int age;

             public Test (string name, int age)
             {
                 this.name = name;
                 this.age = age;
             }
         }

         private void button1_Click (object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
             List <Test> listTest = new List <Test> ();
             listTest.Add (new Test ("Pavel", 30));
             listTest.Add (new Test ("Dima", 48));
             listTest.Add (new Test ("Vova", 48));
             dataGridView1.DataSource = listTest;
         }
```

The DataGridView displays three lines, but no value does not tell me that I had incorrectly

Comment: Have you called `dataGridView1.DataBind()` anywhere on the code?

Comment: WinForm gridview(most of the winform controls) doesn't have a DataBind event.

Comment: Y dont you accept any answers. Pls click the tickmark below the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try making the name and age as properties. It will fix your problem.

```
public class Test
    {
        public string Name
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public int Age
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public Test(string name, int age)
        {
            this.Name = name;
            this.Age = age;
        }
    }
```

Hopes you are using .Net 3.5 or more, otherwise Automatic properties doesn't work.

Here is the screenshot

[image]

Comment: That does not work on my VS2010 with .NET 4.0. Even using properties, setting the DataSource property of a DataGridView to an instance of a List (not BindingList) causes nothing to show up. It works with BindingList, but not List.

Comment: @Telaclavo Did you tried it? I am modified the answer, I added a pic. I just copied the code with automatic properties, VS 2010 C# Express edition works fine.

Comment: Sorry, you are right. I found the problem shortly after that. I was setting DataSource twice (due to a TextChanged event), first time with the list unpopulated, and second time with the list populated, and since the reference to the list was the same, the second assignment to DataSource did not have a refreshing effect. Setting DataSource=null before the DataSource=list assignment solved the problem. Thanks.